# Android Google plus, deep linking

Tags: android, google-plus, deep-linking

I am creating native android application with image gallery.

I want to create a Google plus button for each of my images. When user press +1 I want to publish a post on his wall:

```
user_name like's image_name on my_app
```

And I wish that when clicking on this post it will do the follow:

- clicking on `user_name` will bring you to the users page.
- clicking on `image_name` will bring you to my application and show you this image.
- clicking on `my_app` will bring you to my application, main page.

*If you don't have the app installed it will send you to Google play store, to download it.

How do I do this?
 Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new Google+ Sign-In, you can now create an Interactive Post for your users. This behaves much the same as a normal Share, however, you can add a call to action button (allowing users to "listen" or "RSVP") and a deep link, which will bring a user from their Google+ Stream and into your app.  Also, these posts can be customized with pre-filled text and up to 10 pre-filled recipients.

Learn more at: https://developers.google.com/+/features/interactive-posts.